# Draft.js, is that possible to insert a react component to editor

Tags: draftjs

I need to make a feature like click component  outside of editor, and insert this div component inside to editor, is that possible draft.js can do this? How this can be done?

Comment: Share your code.

Comment: depend on if you want the div be text-editable. if it just a block without text-editing like image, just use custom atomic block. or you need learn the draft rendering model and do much customization other than just insert a div.

Comment: actually, it need a div with a image, link, text insert in the text editor, how that works

Comment: I mean,  does the cursor move into the div and response keyboard press editing?